# Custom Container ViewController Xamarin / Monotouch Example

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, custom-controls, xamarin, uisegmentedcontrol

Does anyone have a simple C# Example showing how you could use Custom Container ViewControllers with Xamarin / Monotouch as per this Apple documentation -

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of posting question, thought would be more helpful to go away and create an example.

https://github.com/wickedw/ViewControllerContainer/blob/master/README.md

**Readme Excerpt**

I got to a point within a project whereby I wanted to display 3 different "Screens" of information based on a user selection.

The TabBarController was not appropriate as the GUI sat within a UINavigationController hierarchy.  Yet, the UISegmentedControl fitted the design well.

I already had my views fully coded as seperate ViewControllers (and not all using the same creation pattern, some used Monotouch Dialog, others Nib files, others Programmatic).

Therefore, I did not want to rewrite existing code to use a Single ViewController controlling multiple Views.

I also thought it was time I looked at "Custom ViewController Containers" as they seemed an ideal fit for this scenario.